# proof-explanation : if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$ , Prove that $A\subseteq C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I have looked quite a few examples regard to the proof of above. they are all similar :

Let  $x\in A$

since $A \subseteq B$ , $x\in A \implies x \in B$

since $B \subseteq C$ , $x\in B \implies x \in C$

therefore   $A\subseteq  C$    //**This is where I don't get it**

how could they  come to the conclusion that $A ⊆ C$  based on $x ∈ C$ ? I mean $x$ is only an element. I can easily give a counter example to disprove it. Let's say $x = 1$, $A = \{ 1,2 \}, B = \{ 1, 2, 3\},  C = \{1,3,7\}$, In this case , $x ∈ A, x ∈ B, x ∈ C$, but It doesn't show that $A ⊆ C$.  However , you might notice the example that $B$ is not a subset of $C$ which contradict the given condition. If that's the case, the question itself is already a proof. why do we need to prove that $x ∈ B$ and $x ∈ C$?

I think I'm missing something, But I don't know what it is , Would you please provide details as much as possible.

Comment: It's because for any $x\in A$ we have $x\in C$.

Comment: You can use transivity of implication from logic: from $p \implies q$ and $q \implies r$, one can deduce that $p \implies r$.

Comment: The proof involves two steps (loosely speaking): (1) First, it shows that for any **particular element** $x$ of $A$ **that** $x$ is also an element of $C$, (2) Second, given any element of $A$ the same argument works **for all** elements of $A$. From (1) and (2) therefore we conclude that $A\subseteq C$.

Comment: X isn't in C if x is 2.  x is ANY element.  So if it's true for a general x it is true for ALL x.

Comment: It's not enough to say x could be 1.  It has to be true for all x.  Xè1 or x=2.

Comment: I have added ([tag:proof-explanation]) tag to show that you are not asking for *any* proof of this claim, but you already have a proof from somewhere and you are asking for explanation of some step(s) in the proof. (Perhaps also the title could be edited in such way that it makes clear that this is about a specific proof...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows that no matter which element of $A$ you choose, it is also an element of $C$. So each element of $A$ is an element of $C$ and hence $A\subseteq C$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$.
If $A\subseteq B\Longrightarrow\forall x\in A,~x\in B$.
If $B\subseteq C\Longrightarrow\forall x\in B,~x\in C$.

***Directed:***
So by transitivity $\forall x\in A\Longrightarrow x\in B\Longrightarrow x\in C\Longrightarrow A\subseteq C$.

***Absurd:***
Suppose $A\not\subseteq C\Longrightarrow\exists x\in A:x\notin C$.
But if $x\in A\Longrightarrow x\in B$, but if $x\in B\Longrightarrow x\in C$.
So $x\in C~\wedge x\notin C$, then the hypothesis was false, so $A\subseteq C$.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that not only for a single element, being in $A$ implies being in $C$, but as the arguument is valid for any $x$, we can have inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed your counter example won't disprove the statement in the question title, as the $B\subseteq C$ assumption is key.

You have that, for any $x\in A$, we have $x\in B$ since $A\subseteq B$. You also have that, for any $y\in B$, we have $y\in C$ since $B\subseteq C$. So, any element $x\in A$ is also in $C$, since every element of $A$ is in $B$, and every element of $B$ is in $C$. Showing that, for an arbitrary $x\in A$ we have $x\in C$ is precisely what it means for $A$ to be contained in $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A $ is not a subset of $C$.

this means there exist $a \in A $ which is not in $C $.

$A\subset B $ and $a \in A $

$$\implies a\in B. $$

$a\in B $ and $B\subset C $
$$\implies a\in C $$

and this is the contradiction.

Comment: If I read the question correctly, it seems to me that what OP wants is an a clarification of the proof that is posted on the body of the question and not a separate proof. Isn't it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @user170039 It belongs to him to decide if this answer is helpful or not.

Comment: It is 3 am in Morocco and i prefer to sleep now and play with other users . I hope you will find many reasons to downvote and make yourself satisfied. bye.

Comment: If your "you" in the last comment was referred to me (which may not be the case) then let me inform you that I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: @user170039 It is an other "you" not you.

Comment: Sorry for causing conflicts here. Anyone's answer is appreciated.